sum(nvl not aggregating properly sql
I am using dbeaver 23.3.3 and I am wondering why my SQL query is not aggregating properly and if anyone knows a fix to this?
Here is my query:
select
     weeknum,
     year,
     coalesce(sum(orders),0) as orders,
     coalesce(sum(fc),0) as fc
     from table_1
group by
     weeknum,
     year,
     orders

but the results are not aggregating properly
Query Output:



orders
fc
year
weeknum




0
0
2024
50


25
10
2024
50


0
0
2024
51


15
8
2024
51



what i hope to achieve is this:



orders
fc
year
weeknum




25
10
2024
50


15
8
2024
51



Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Try to remove orders from the GROUP BY clause

@JonasMetzler it is returning this error:
ERROR: column "orders" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I can't reproduce your issue. See https://dbfiddle.uk/4e86JKbX Please modify the fiddle, so it illustrates the problem and then share the new url

Dbeaver is just an IDE. What is the DBMS? Regardless, removing "orders" from group by should resolve this as mentioned above.

You appear to be just trying to filter on an aggregated column, If this is the case then just use a HAVING clause e.g. HAVING coalesce(sum(orders),0) > 0

The query is malformed. You cannot nest multiple aggregations in the same query scope. Voting to close.

@TheImpaler why do you think the query is malformed? It runs without any issues, it’s just not giving the questioner the answer they want

If it was malformed, it wouldn't produce a result. See the fiddle I linked. Just remove orders from the GROUP BY clause and it works fine.

@NickW An aggregate function cannot be aggregated again in the same query scope (this can be resolved with subqueries). See fiddle. This query may run on MySQL/MariaDB, however; if it runs, the results are probably unpredicable.

@TheImpaler apologies, I missed the ‘orders’ in the group by
